# Find multiple tags with multiple search parameters with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have html code that looks something like this (the soup):

```
<label for="02" class="highlited">"Some text here"</label>
<span class="type3 type3-display">
<label for="01" class="highlited">"Some text here"</label>
<span class="type1 type1-display">
<label> Somete text here </label>
<span class="type999 type999-display">
<span class="type1 type1-display">
```

I have to grab both the labels and the spans from the page but with multiple search parameters.

- for the labels i have to grab only those that contains for= (any text inside)
- for the spans i have to grab only those that contain a word in a list e.g

> myList = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3']

- The order as they are found on the page must be respected

the result I need would look like this:

```
<label for="02" class="highlited">"Some text here"</label>
<span class="type3 type3-display">
<label for="01" class="highlited">"Some text here"</label>
<span class="type1 type1-display">
<span class="type1 type1-display">
```

To find the labels that contain anything after "for=" i use the following code:

```
soup.find_all('label', {'for': re.compile('.*')}) # it works as expected
```

But now i need to also find all the spans with specific wording and respect the order as they are found on the web page.

I tried this but it didn't worked:

```
soup.find_all(['label', 'span'], [{'for': re.compile('.*')}, {'class': 'type1'}], recursive=False) # here i just used {'class': 'type1'} becase I don't know how to pass in a list to soup to search for a match)
```

Thank you in advance!

edit: I also tried to combine 2 find_all() searches with (+) but then i loose the order.
edit2: spelling

Comment: when you say spans that contains words in list e.g. type1 do you mean that have class attribute containing type1, type2 etc? And also, is it sufficient to simply say class contains type? Or must the number be specified as well? And should there be some closing tags on the spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without regex as well.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<label for="02" class="highlited">"Some text here"</label>
<span class="type3 type3-display"></span>
<label for="01" class="highlited">"Some text here"</label>
<span class="type1 type1-display"></span>
<label> Somete text here </label>
<span class="type999 type999-display"></span>
<span class="type1 type1-display"></span>'''

myList = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3']
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all():
    if (item.name=='label') and 'for' in item.attrs :
       print(item)
    if (item.name == 'span') and item['class'][0] in myList :
        print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
<label class="highlited" for="02">"Some text here"</label>
<span class="type3 type3-display"></span>
<label class="highlited" for="01">"Some text here"</label>
<span class="type1 type1-display"></span>
<span class="type1 type1-display"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you that is perfect - I wasn't aware that I could do it like in your solution.

But also, please, do provide your first solution, might be useful to some other people that come across your answer!